# How to prevent XSS and CSRF globally in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, xss, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I want to prevent my application from `XSS` and `CSRF` attacks, I want to make some global check to prevent these.

I have used below code in `statup` file in `ConfigureServices` function, it prevents CSRF attacks but I am not sure is it enough to prevent both the attacks or do I need to write some code to prevent XSS separately.

```
services.AddMvc(options => 
    options.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()));
```

**One more doubt**: will it work for an API application?

Comment: Have a look at the NWebSec packages - especially the middleware and the tag helpers. As mentioned in below answer, you're really asking two different questions because they're two different attack vectors and the answer to both is never "this will fix everything". It's always an and-and story. But I digress. NWebSec allows you to cover some basic groundwork without reinventing the wheel. Plenty of articles on that topic but you might as well start [here](https://damienbod.com/2018/02/08/adding-http-headers-to-improve-security-in-an-asp-net-mvc-core-application/).

Answer (score 2):

XSS and CSRF are completely different kinds of attacks which have to be defended against in completely different ways.

XSS requires that user input be appropriately escaped for the very specific context in which it is inserted. There is no panacea for it. You cannot solve it globally. (There are various techniques which look for suspicious content in requests which *might* be XSS but they are rather prone to throwing false positives).

Comment: Or even worse, false negatives. :)